# Is there a Lightroom lens correction profile for the Nikon Coolpix 995?

Tags: lightroom, coolpix, lens-correction

I have a bunch of old photos taken with a Nikon Coolpix 995 that I'm working with in Lightroom 3. The 995 had noticeable lens distortion particularly at the wideangle end.

I've tried using Lightroom's Coolpix P6000 profile for correction, and it makes things a lot better - but I was wondering if there's a specific profile for the 995 available somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I've never chanced to run acrosss one, but then, I wasn't looking. Even if there isn't one, you can always *create* one using the [Adobe Lens Profile Creator](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/) utility. That goes for any other camera as well, including digital scans from old or obscure film camera transparencies, negatives or prints.

Comment: I don't actually have the camera anymore - can I still do something useful with this tool?

Comment: @Roddy — not really. If you can beg, borrow or steal one for an hour or so, that will be long enough to shoot the target prints (there's a PDF set to print out) to get a proper profile. There is a way to approximate a profile if you have pictures that have regular geometric details (walls shot straight on and so on), but it won't be perfect, and it will only provide geometric correction (it can't get the vignetting or aberrations).